# How i can pass data to controller in ajax using asp MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have login form can user write username and password and i check if the username right or not i'm try to send the username to Home controller by ajax that's my controller code

```
          [HttpPost]
       public JsonResult ValidateUser(string username,string password)
    {
        using(var contxt=new EnglisCenterEntities())
        {
            var data = from a in contxt.Employee
                       where a.Username == username && a.Passwords == password
                       select a.EmpName;
            string Empname = data.FirstOrDefault();
            if(data.Count()>0)
            {

                return Json(new { Success = true } ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my ajax code

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

               $('#savedata').click(function (e) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           var data = {
                               username: function () { return $("#username").val(); },
                               password: function () { return $("#password").val(); }

                           };

                           $.ajax({
                               url: "/Account/validateuser",
                               type: "POST",
                               data: data,
                               dataType: "json",

                               success: function (response) {





                                       window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";

                                   }
                                   else
                                       notifyBar();
                                       @*window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";*@
                               },

                               error: function () {
                                   console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                               }
                           });
                       });
});
```

this code check if the user exist or not and it's working but i want to send the user name with redirect the Index action. How i can do that?

Comment: Why are you using functions here: `username: function () { /* */ },` instead of actual value?

Comment: I was  Using username:$("#username").val() before but it's was not working. after i changed to this method became work

Comment: Twice before you have asked this question and twice you have accepted wrong answers. And using ajax to post when you want to redirect is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
var xsrf = 'username=' + username + '&password='+password;
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/validateuser",
    type: "POST",
    data: xsrf ,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }...
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Url.Action` you can  send additional data:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Name = "yourUserName" })
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure Data sends by Ajax (key,value) pair. those key are same(case sensitive)

**hear i show, you are send key: username and you controller receive : Username**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#savedata').click(function (e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       var data = {
                           username: function () { return $("#username").val(); },
                           password: function () { return $("#password").val(); }

                       };

                       $.ajax({
                           url: "/Account/validateuser",
                           type: "POST",
                           data: data,
                           dataType: "json",

                           success: function (response) {





                                   window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";

                               }
                               else
                                   notifyBar();
                                   @*window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";*@
                           },

                           error: function () {
                               console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                           }
                       });
                   });
```

});